# Passing parameters to a button's command option

Tags: python, function, tkinter

How do I use a function with parameters for a button?

```
from Tkinter import *
def function(x, y):
    x * y

root = Tk()
button_1 = Button(root, text='Times two numbers', command=function)
```

So how do I pass it? Would I:

```
button_1 = Button(root, text='Times two numbers', command=function(z,v))
```

If that doesn't work can someone please explain how it works I saw people using `lambda` but I don't understand it.

Comment: where will you get the value of z, v?

Comment: @RafaelBarros - I think that `z` and `v` are just placeholders for real arguments.  The OP was just giving an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `lambda` for this:

```
button_1 = Button(root, text='Times two numbers', command=lambda: function(z,v))
```

[`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) creates what is known as an [anonymous function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function).  It is equivalent to doing:

```
def callback():
    function(z,v)
button_1 = Button(root, text='Times two numbers', command=callback)
```

except that the function is created inline.

---

Note that you cannot do:

```
button_1 = Button(root, text='Times two numbers', command=function(z,v))
```

because `function(z,v)` is a valid function call and will be executed as such when Python interprets the above line.  So, `command` will be assigned to the return value of `function(z,v)`.

Comment: I now understand the lambda a bit more but didn't understand the second part, so I will use lambda thanks.

Comment: The second part was just showing what the equivalent code would be using `def` instead of `lambda`.  Let me also explain why your current solution does not work...see my edit.