# How to change font options

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts, notepad

I want to make a sort of notepad editor with Python Tkinter, that has a menu where I can edit the font (the size and style of it).

I keep getting errors, no matter what I try. I am new to Python though, so it might be that I am making an obvious mistake. I hope someone can help.

When I click on "Opmaak" (i.e. layout) and then on "Lettergrootte" (i.e. font size) I would like an option menu to pop up where I can change the font size and style -- but instead I get the following error:

```
> Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AppData\Local\Mu\pkgs\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: __opmaak() missing 1 required positional argument: 'nieuweFont'
```

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk 
import os  
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.messagebox import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *

class Kladblok:
    __root = Tk()

    __thisBreedte = 300
    __thisHoogte = 300
    __thisTekstVlak = Text(__root) 
    __thisMenuBar = Menu(__root) 
    __thisBestandMenu = Menu(__thisMenuBar, tearoff=0) 
    __thisBewerkenMenu = Menu(__thisMenuBar, tearoff=0)
    __thisOpmaakMenu = Menu(__thisMenuBar, tearoff=0)
    __thisHelpMenu = Menu(__thisMenuBar, tearoff=0) 
    __thisScrollBar = Scrollbar(__thisTekstVlak)      
    __bestand = None

    def __init__(self,**kwargs): 

        try: 
            self.__root.wm_iconbitmap("Notepad.ico")  
        except: 
            pass

        try: 
            self.__thisBreedte = kwargs['breedte'] 
        except KeyError: 
            pass

        try: 
            self.__thisHoogte = kwargs['hoogte'] 
        except KeyError: 
            pass

        self.__root.title("Naamloos - Kladblok") 

        screenBreedte = self.__root.winfo_screenwidth() 
        screenHoogte = self.__root.winfo_screenheight() 

        links = (screenBreedte / 2) - (self.__thisBreedte / 2)  

        top = (screenHoogte / 2) - (self.__thisHoogte /2)  

        self.__root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (self.__thisBreedte, self.__thisHoogte, links, top))  

        self.__root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1) 
        self.__root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) 

        self.__thisTekstVlak.grid(sticky = N + E + S + W)

        self.__thisBestandMenu.add_command(label="Nieuw", command=self.__nieuwBestand) 

        self.__thisBestandMenu.add_command(label="Open", command=self.__openBestand) 

        self.__thisBestandMenu.add_command(label="Opslaan", command=self.__opslaanBestand)

        self.__thisBestandMenu.add_separator()                                          
        self.__thisBestandMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.__exitBestand) 
        self.__thisMenuBar.add_cascade(label="Bestand", menu=self.__thisBestandMenu)

        self.__thisOpmaakMenu.add_command(label="Lettergrootte", command=self.__opmaak)

        self.__thisMenuBar.add_cascade(label="Opmaak", menu=self.__thisOpmaakMenu)

        self.__thisBewerkenMenu.add_command(label="Knippen", command=self.__knippen)              

        self.__thisBewerkenMenu.add_command(label="Kopieren", command=self.__kopieeren)          

        self.__thisBewerkenMenu.add_command(label="Plakken", command=self.__plakken)          

        self.__thisMenuBar.add_cascade(label="Bewerken", menu=self.__thisBewerkenMenu)    

        self.__thisHelpMenu.add_command(label="Over mij", command=self.__overMij)
        self.__thisMenuBar.add_cascade(label="Help mij", menu=self.__thisHelpMenu) 

        self.__root.config(menu=self.__thisMenuBar) 

        self.__thisScrollBar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)                     

        # Scrollbar will adjust automatically according to the content         
        self.__thisScrollBar.config(command=self.__thisTekstVlak.yview)      
        self.__thisTekstVlak.config(yscrollcommand=self.__thisScrollBar.set) 

    def __exitBestand(self): 
        self.__root.destroy()

    def __nieuwBestand(self): 
        self.__root.title("Naamloos - Kladblok") 
        self.__bestand = None
        self.__thisTekstVlak.delete(1.0,END) 

    def __openBestand(self): 

        self.__bestand = askopenfilename(defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=[("Alle bestanden","*.*"), ("Tekst bestanden","*.txt")]) 

        if self.__bestand == "": 
            self.__bestand = None

        else: 
            self.__root.title(os.path.basename(self.__bestand) + " - Kladblok") 
            self.__thisTekstVlak.delete(1.0,END) 

            bestand = open(self.__bestand,"r") 

            self.__thisTekstVlak.insert(1.0,bestand.read()) 

            bestand.close() 

    def __opslaanBestand(self):
        if self.__bestand == None: 
            self.__bestand = asksaveasfilename(initialfile='Naamloos.txt', defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=[("Alle bestanden","*.*"), ("Tekst bestanden","*.txt")]) 

            if self.__bestand == "": 
                self.__bestand = None

            else: 
                bestand = open(self.__bestand,"w") 
                bestand.write(self.__thisTekstVlak.get(1.0,END)) 
                bestand.close() 

                self.__root.title(os.path.basename(self.__bestand) + " - Kladblok") 

        else: 
            bestand = open(self.__bestand,"w") 
            bestand.write(self.__thisTekstVlak.get(1.0,END)) 
            bestand.close() 

    def __knippen(self): 
        self.__thisTekstVlak.event_generate("<<Cut>>") 

    def __kopieeren(self): 
        self.__thisTekstVlak.event_generate("<<Copy>>") 

    def __plakken(self): 
        self.__thisTekstVlak.event_generate("<<Paste>>")    

    def __overMij(self):
        showinfo("Kladblok", "Copyright Timbo") 

    def __nieuweFont(self, *args):
        nieuweFont = (font.get(), fontSize.get())
        open['font'] = nieuweFont
        return nieuweFont

    def __opmaak(self, nieuweFont):
        font = StringVar(self.__root)
        font.set("Times")
        font.trace("w", nieuweFont)
        fontOptions = OptionMenu(self.__root, font, "Arial", "Times", "Helvetica", "Comic")

    #start programma
    def start(self): 
        self.__root.mainloop()

kladblok = Kladblok(width=600,height=400) 
kladblok.start()
```

Any assistance with fixing my code would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The line which raised error is not in the code.

Comment: There is no other code, that's just what happens. It has to do with the two functions "__nieuweFont(self, *args)" and "__opmaak(self)". Before I tried to get a menu where I can change the font size and style, everything worked.

Comment: In your `__opmaak` function you use `__root` twice where you should use `self.__root`.

Comment: Hello, 
With that I get a different error, which is very vague:

"File "- my path file -", line 1
SyntaxError: encoding problem: utf8"

Comment: I can't reproduce that error.

Comment: Hello, I have edited the code a little so that the utf8 is removed. Now I get the error "TypeError: __opmaak() missing 1 required positional argument: 'nieuweFont'" I have no idea how to get rid of this though, I have given nieuweFont as a parameter, otherwise it would say: "NameError: name 'nieuweFont' is not defined".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing parameters to a button's command option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892640/passing-parameters-to-a-buttons-command-option)

Comment: That doesn't look like what I tried. There he wants to use a function with parameters as command in a button, but I just want to use a variable.

Comment: Your `__opmaak` function is called by the `__thisOpmaakMenu` Menu item, which doesn't pass any arguments. Your `__opmaak` function does expect an argument to be passed though: `nieuweFont`, because you defined it as `def __opmaak(self, nieuweFont):`.  Because `__opmaak` requires an argument to be passed but it isn't you get this error.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not quite certain what you mean. `nieuweFont` is given as parameter in my `__opmaak` function, as it is used there, in the following line: `font.trace("w", nieuweFont)`, so I have to give it as parameter. I can't give `nieuweFont` as parameter anywhere else, as it gets defined in the function above it, `__nieuweFont`.

Answer (score 0):

As @fhdrsdg pointed out, your object __opmaak, which you defined as

```
      def __opmaak(self,nieuweFont)
```

expects you to pass two arguments: self(which is passed by default) and nieuweFont. but the widget command style you are implementing does not give room for that.

```
            self.__thisOpmaakMenu.add_command(label="Lettergrootte", command=self.__opmaak)
```

This passes the self argument by default, but it does not give room for passing your second argument, hence the error:

```
           TypeError: __opmaak() missing 1 required positional argument: 'nieuweFont'
```

If you intend to pass an argument to a tkinter widget, you should use a lambda function.
Your code should be more like:

```
       self.__thisOpmaakMenu.add_command(label="Lettergrootte", command=lambda: self.__opmaak(nieuweFont))
```

This passes the self argument by default and also gives you room to pass the second required argument nieuweFont

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, but then I get this error:                    
`Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AppData\Local\Mu\pkgs\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "-my file path-", line 64, in <lambda>
    self.__thisOpmaakMenu.add_command(label="Lettergrootte", command=lambda: self.__opmaak(nieuweFont))
NameError: name 'nieuweFont' is not defined`                                                     I assume this is because I have not defined nieuweFont yet, but how should I then?

Comment: You will get that error because from your code, the variable 'nieuweFont' is a local variable. You should initialize it as self.nieuweFont or define it as a global variable which ever is appropriate to what you are implementing. Also, considering the widget might be clicked before the function where you initialized 'nieuweFont' is called, you will be better served initializing it in your __init__ function

Comment: if you have `self.nieuweFont = (font.get(), fontSize.get())` initialized in `__init__` then you can pass it as `self.__thisOpmaakMenu.add_command(label="Lettergrootte", command=lambda: self.__opmaak(self.nieuweFont))` to your widget.

Comment: Thank you, now I don't get any errors anymore. But how will I now be able to get what I ultimately want; changing font styles/sizes by clicking on there, as what is right now in the `__nieuweFont` and `__opmaak` functions, do nothing.

EDIT: I didn't see your new message, will do that now.

Comment: Because I intialized `self.nieuweFont` in `__init__`, it now says that `NameError: name 'font' is not defined`. Just like how `fontSize` is not defined. How would I tackle that, should I make them global or..?

Comment: you must import font: `from tkinter import font`. and I think you need to study this: [NMT doc](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/fonts.html) and [tkdocs](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/fonts.html)

Comment: If your original question was answered, you will help other users by marking the post as an answered.

Comment: I am still trying to figure it out, so far without much luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide minimal code not the whole project!

Your error is you pass one argument but two was expected.

possible solution:

```
from tkinter import * 

class Kladblok:

    def __init__(self, master): 
        self.font1 = font=("Open Sans Standard",16,"bold")
        self.font2 = font=("Times",12,"bold")
        self.master = master
        self.__thisTekstVlak = Text(self.master, font=self.font1) 
        self.__thisMenuBar = Menu(self.master) 
        self.__thisOpmaakMenu = Menu(self.__thisMenuBar, tearoff=0)
        self.__thisScrollBar = Scrollbar(self.__thisTekstVlak) 

        self.master.title("Naamloos - Kladblok")  
        self.master.geometry(("300x300"))  
        self.master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1) 
        self.master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) 
        self.__thisTekstVlak.grid(sticky = N + E + S + W)

        self.__thisOpmaakMenu.add_command(label="Lettergrootte", command=lambda: self.__opmaak(self.font2))

        self.__thisMenuBar.add_cascade(label="Opmaak", menu=self.__thisOpmaakMenu)
        self.master.config(menu=self.__thisMenuBar) 

        self.__thisScrollBar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)                     

        # Scrollbar will adjust automatically according to the content         
        self.__thisScrollBar.config(command=self.__thisTekstVlak.yview)      
        self.__thisTekstVlak.config(yscrollcommand=self.__thisScrollBar.set) 

    def __opmaak(self, nieuweFont):
        self.__thisTekstVlak.configure(font=nieuweFont)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    kladblok = Kladblok(root) 
    root.mainloop()
```